# Can application.properties and application.yml be mixed?

Tags: spring, mongodb, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

Using spring-boot version 1.2.5

In development, I'm trying to default my application to use a mongo database hosted locally with vagrant

```
./gradlew bootrun
```

In aws, I want to use a mongo database hosted on an ec2 instance

```
jar -jar my.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=aws
```

## application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=development
```

## application.yml

```
spring:
    profiles: development
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 10.11.12.13
            port: 27017
---
spring:
    profiles: aws
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: ec2-xyz.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            port: 27017
```

However, When running in development, mongo tries to connect on localhost:27017 (which is the default spring-mongo behavior)

**EDIT:** Actually, I think this is working. I'm not sure what was originally causing an error

**EDIT:** I can also probably move all of this into the YAML file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original solution was actually correct.

I ended up moving `application.properties` into `application.yml`.

## application.yml

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: development
---
spring:
    profiles: development
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 10.11.12.13
            port: 27017
---
spring:
    profiles: aws
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: ec2-x-y-z-a.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            port: 27017
```

---

The development profile could be made the 'default'

## application.yml with development configuration as default

```
spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 10.11.12.13
            port: 27017
---
spring:
    profiles: aws
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: ec2-x-y-z-a.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```